# Best way to store Large String in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2005 and 2008 R2 databases, and I need to store large string which may contains over 50 thousands characters. Currently I am using the data type `nvarchar(max)` to store larger string.

My problem with `nvarchar(max)` is it takes more storage space in database. I have tested with **100000** records and it takes around **10 GB** memory to store **100000** records.

Here, one good point is, I don't use this column for SQL `Where` query purpose, so that I have decided to store the data as `BLOB` data type - `nvarbinary(max)`. In this way the storage memory decreased 50%, it means, it takes around **5 GB** memory to store **100000** records.

So my question, since I am not going to use this string data for SQL `Where` query purpose, I would like to store it in any other better way, so that the database size will be reduced below **5 GB**.

Hope, someone will give better idea!

Comment: If you do not use that data for query purposes, why do you store it? To be more precise, for what purposes do you use that data? Does it really necessary to store in the DB (can you store it in files and store only the path to the files?)

Comment: Good question, I am using Database for our product not for my own project..The product will be installed by only customers. So customers always asks us store data only in database and don't create any file so that they can maintain database history easily.

Comment: I won't use only in SQL Where clause, but I will use it Select clause whenever it needs

Comment: If this is **textual** data you're storing - please don't store it as `Varbinary` - this is just too cumbersome. If storing it as varbinary seems to reduce storage space by 50%, I'm assuming this is **non-Unicode** text that would easily fit into `varchar(max)`. `nvarchar` datatype is a **Unicode** string - each character uses **2 bytes** of storage. If you use `varchar` instead, each character uses only **1 byte** of storage (but you won't be able to store Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc. texts in such a column)

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server 2008 you have the option to use [`FILESTREAM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) to store large binary data. In this case, the data will be available in queries, but physically stored on the filesystem.

Microsoft published a [SQL Server Technical Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480) which contains usefull information about how and when to use `FILESTREAM`. On the 8th page, the comparsion chart shows that the *FILESTREAM has advantage* over BLOBs stored in database *if the stored data is larger than 1MB*.

**NOTE** FILESTREAM is not available in SQL Server 2005! (And [SQL Server 2005 is no longer supported by Microsoft](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=sql+server+2005&Filter=FilterNO) - except the extended support)

**Some more articles to read**

You can see some comparsion charts on [SQLSkills blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-filestream-performance/) about its performance.

Also Microsoft Research published a [Technical Article: To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) about filestreams and BLOBS.

You can give it a try, but as always, you have to run some environment specific test to be sure that this solution works or not. If this is a product on the market, it is a good idea to implement the FILESTREAM support as an opt-in or opt-out feature.

**Just a side-note**

`NVARCHAR` is twice as large than `VARBINARY` because SQL Server stores each character on 2 bytes in the unicode (`NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, etc) columns.